# Launch image not showing on device but shows on simulator xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

I've uploaded my images to my target, (640x1136) for each, but for some reason when I run on my iPhone 5 it's not working. When I run it on my emulator "iPhone Retina (4 inch)" it works. Is there something that I'm missing?[image]

Comment: Background image names are case sensitive. could you check that ?

Comment: What do you mean? I just drag and dropped into this interface?

Comment: so it should be fine. but check that your `info.plist` reflects the images names on your file system. I had that once, it was due to casing.

Comment: try Deleting the app from your Device, then Clean the code and try again.

Comment: So the casing looks right in `info.plist`. I tried the delete and clean thing also with no luck. I just noticed I get a couple of warnings. `/Images.xcassets: LaunchImage.launchimage/Splash_screen.png is 640x1136 but should be 640x960.` I'm on an iphone 5 device

Comment: So I kinda did a hack. I put this image in my dropbox folder, opened it, took a screenshot, sent it to myself, dragged that into the interface and now it works...weird